# XML Syntax example of starting a KieWorkbench business process from SoapUI

Tags: xml, soap, drools, kie, business-process

I am trying to start a process i have defined in a Kie Workbench project from SoapUI 5.2.1.

At the moment i am getting a "Unknown process ID: null" response when i POST to the container.

This is my XML i am using to POST:

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultKieSession">
    <insert out-identifier="$input">
        <principa.mysoapuiproject.Person>
            <IDNumber>9211035217086</IDNumber>
        </principa.mysoapuiproject.Person>
    </insert>
    <start-process processID="IDValidationProcess"/>
</batch-execution>
```

This is the response i get:

```
<response type="FAILURE" msg="Error calling container testingMyProcessWithSoap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown process ID: null"/>
```

If i do the following POST with "fire-all-rules" instead of "start-process" (see code below)

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultKieSession">
    <insert out-identifier="$input">
        <principa.mysoapuiproject.Person>
            <IDNumber>9211035217086</IDNumber>
        </principa.mysoapuiproject.Person>
    </insert>
    <fire-all-rules/>
</batch-execution>
```

Then it produces the following response:

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Container testingMyProcessWithSoap successfully called.">
   <results><![CDATA[<execution-results>
  <result identifier="$input">
    <principa.mysoapuiproject.Person>
      <IDNumber>9211035217086</IDNumber>
      <gender>0</gender>
      <valid>false</valid>
      <sequence>0</sequence>
      <SACitizen>false</SACitizen>
      <partialScore1>0.0</partialScore1>
      <partialScore2>0.0</partialScore2>
      <partialScore3>0.0</partialScore3>
      <partialScore4>0.0</partialScore4>
      <partialScore5>0.0</partialScore5>
      <finalScore>0.0</finalScore>
    </principa.mysoapuiproject.Person>
  </result>
  <fact-handle identifier="$input" external-form="0:20:1519217749:1519217749:20:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT"/>
</execution-results>]]></results>
</response>
```

The response looks as expected: i only have one Rule in my project which is assigned to a Ruleflow-Group called "CallFunction", so i don't expect any rules to fire when stating to fire-all-rules.

Can anyone give me an example of how the XML POST request should look? Or any advice with regards to SoapUI + Kie Workbench would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. My process name wasn't set to IDValidationProcess; it was set to MySoapUIProject.IDValidationProcess. Call produces successful results from the POST request now.